# Why is gzip compression slower for me?

Tags: php, performance, load, gzip

Why is http://storyfollower.com slower when I use gzip?

Check the data bellow:

With compression:
Load time
1.99s
Page size
586.2kB
Perf. grade
83/100
Archived: http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/nE0Jnn7Hp/http://storyfollower.com

Without Compression
Load time
835ms
Page size
756.2kB
Perf. grade
79/100
Archived: http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/nFmp4l3Ez/storyfollower.com

thanks

Comment: This is probably due to the fact that it has to decompress the data if it's compressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A nice way to have both gzip and low cpu overhead is using a cdn and storing the gziped files there

Answer (score 5):

Most of the overhead is waiting for the server to send data. I guess that is the time needed to compress the data.

Using compression for the page under test gains you very little: 587Kb -> 756Kb, so the CPU overhead is greater than what you gain from sending smaller data.

I'd suggest you try with another page which sends more data. If you don't have such pages, then using compression is probably not the best choice.